# SmartCard Reader UMDF driver. Power down problems

Tags: driver, smartcard, smartcard-reader, umdf

Working on a UMDF card-reader driver which connects to a software based SmartCard simulator thus allowing any PC/SC compliant application to interface to the SmartCard simulator.

Implementation based on Fabio Ottavi's project here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/BixVReader.aspx

Works well except that the Windows SmartCard Service puts the driver into power-down mode (IOCTL_SMARTCARD_POWER -> SCARD_POWER_DOWN) when it reports IOCTL_SMARTCARD_IS_PRESENT. This happens when the driver is not been currently accessed by another application. The power-down generally happends 10 to 15 seconds after the card is present and I would like to prevent it happening.

Fabio mentions an undocumented Windows7 registry entry (CardDisconnectPowerDownDelay), however, this did not seem to work and I need a solution for XP as well.

Thanks...

Comment: Excuse me, Hugh, have you solve this problem?